# Docker container vs Java Virtual Machine

Tags: java, docker, jvm, containers, virtualization

Is it true to say that to a high degree what is now done in docker containers can also be done in java with jvm if someone wanted to ?

Besides being able to write an application in your own language and having much customisation flexibility does docker basically do what Java has been doing with its virtual machine for ages ? i.e. it provides executable environment separate from the underlying OS.

Comment: The short answer is no. The long answer is too long for SE.

Answer (score 6):

Generally Docker containers cannot be done "within Java" because Docker serves to encapsulate the application, and "within Java" is the code being loaded after the JVM launches.

The JVM is already running when it parses the class it will search for the `main` method.  So encapsulation at the process level can't be done because the process (the JVM) is already running.

Java has encapsulation techniques which do provide protection between various Java elements (see class loader hierarchies in Tomcat, for an example); but those only isolate "application plugins" from each other, the main process that is running them all is Tomcat, which is really a program loaded into an already running JVM.

This doesn't mean you can't combine the two to achieve some object, it just means that the types of isolation provided between the two products isn't interchangeable.

Comment: I understand what you're saying about encapsulation but in the end isn't that just two different ways to achieve the same thing i.e. have an application running on a virtual machine ?

Comment: It is not two ways of doing the same thing, it is two ways of doing different things, being confused to the point that you think they're the same.  Consider the Java program to be a "shared library" used by the JVM.  Consider docker to be a more-portable wrapper around an executable.  Since the JVM is the executable, it wouldn't make sense to put docker around the shared library, you'd put it around the Java executable (JVM) and the shared library (your main launching JAR file).

Answer (score 4):

> what is now done in docker containers can also be done in java with jvm   someone wanted to

Short Answer: No. You could wrap a docker container around your JVM, but you cannot wrap a JVM around a docker container, non-trivially.

> docker basically do what Java has been doing with its virtual machine for ages ? i.e. it provides executable environment separate from the underlying OS.

Docker containers provide isolation from other containers without introducing a virtualisation layer. Thus, they are different and more performant than VMs.

Answer (score 0):

Docker can perform several things that the Java JVM cannot do however, programming in Java and running on the JVM will provide several of the advantages of running in a Docker container.
I work on a large Java project and this project is 20 years old. We have been evolving and fixing our application without any tools or compatibility issues for all these years. Also, as a bonus, the application is platform independent. Several components of it can run in both Windows and Linux. Because no effort was made initially to build a multiplatform application, there is one component that cannot run on Linux. But it would be relatively easy to make it work on that platform.
It would have been much more difficult to do the same thing using C or C++ and associated toolchain.

Comment: What can docker do that the JVM can't?

Comment: Docker will isolate your application from more elements than the JVM and will allow doing this for applications that are not written in Java.
It is another step up the ladder.

Comment: The question was intended to improve your answer.  That's one point: can be used with languages aside from Java (so can the JVM in fact: it's a common compilation target).  What isolation does it provide that the JVM doesn't?

Comment: Yes. Good catch. I should have said that docker will provide isolation for applications written in languages other than those that target the JVM.
For example, you could write a native application in C/C++, Nim, Rust, ...